# How to catch user prompts in ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have an sql script which asks for user input in the command line.

How can I somehow catch this prompt with some criteria and input some text while running ansible script?

**upd:**

I need to catch requests for manual input and instead of manually input values, input them programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at [expect](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/expect_module.html) module.

```
# Case insensitve password string match
- expect:
    command: passwd username
    responses:
      (?i)password: "MySekretPa$$word"
```

Comment: Thanks but this seems like it is not what I want. I added an update to the post.

Comment: @Alexander.Iljushkin how is your updated info different to what expect does? expect is there exactly for this reason: to run a command and response to any prompts for input.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out